# What's the most (performance) efficient and readable way to 'split' a generic list based on a condition?

Tags: c#, linq, performance

(highly simplified example)
I have a generic list of strings:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "abc", "owla", "paula", "lala", "hop" };
```

I'm looking for the most efficient way to split this list into a list with elements that meet a condition and a list of elements that don't meet that same condition.

```
Func<string, bool> condition = s => s.IndexOf("o") > -1;
Predicate<string> kickOut = s => s.IndexOf("o") > -1;
var stringsThatMeetCondition = strings.Where(condition);
strings.RemoveAll(kickOut);
var stringsThatDontMeetCondition = strings;
```

Is there a way to do this with looping only once through the original list?

Comment: The `Where` extension method chucks out an `IEnumerable<T>` but the `RemoveAll` is an in-place operation. As such you're comparing fundamentally different operations. What is "writing efficiency"? Concise, terse, easy to understand? You don't make it clear.

Comment: Be very careful altering a list over which you have an unmaterialized query. The deferred nature of LINQ makes this inadvisable (although your example *should* be ok)

Comment: What's concise? What's terse? :) (I'm not native English)
I mean easy readable / understand.
Is my code correct now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
IEnumerable<T> FilterAndRemove(this List<T> list, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
  List<T> filtered = new List<T>();
  int i = 0;
  while(i < list.Count)
  {
     if (pred(list[i]))
     {
        filtered.Add(list[i]);
        list.RemoveAt(i);
     }
     else
     { 
        ++i;
     }
  }
  return list;
}
```

But am sure you have already thought of something similar. Can you please update your answer with the kind of efficiency that you seek?

Note that two filtering runs with `pred` and `!pred` over the original list would still be O(n) and not at all inefficient. Especially considering that you'd get the full benefit of lazy evaluation for both result sets. See also Rob's answer.

This algorithm is in O(n^2).

Instead removing each element, you can also collect them in a new list and copy them over to the input list before returning. This will also get you O(n).

One more option for O(n) would be switching to a linked list.

Comment: I'm tempted to go for this one.. Is it correct it's only looping the original list once?

Comment: @TweeZz Yes, it only loops once, but note the `RemoveAt(i)` which bumps this algorithm to O(n^2). I posted this answer because it does exactly what your example code does, meaning it mutates the list. I personally would do it like in Rob's or Snowbear JIM-compiler's answers. What is the use case for your code, and why is it performance critical?

Comment: IMO performance for this is not really critical. But the team lead is kinda trying to save as many CPU cycles as possible ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use some linq:

```
var matches = list.Select(s => s.IndexOf("o") > -1).ToList();
var notMatches = list.Except(matches).ToList();
list.Clear();
list.AddRange(matches);
```

**Update:** as has been mentioned in the comments, be careful mutating the list as linq methods try to be on-demand, they will not iterate the list until you start looking into the `IEnumerable`.  However in my case, I call `ToList`, which effectively causes it to run through the entire list of items.

Comment: Select just returns a list, right?
Does it also modify the original list instance?
I mean that I need to end up with 2 lists. This would give me a list of items matching the condition and the original list, right?

Comment: Select *doesn't* return a list. It returns an `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: No, just returns an IEnumerable.  Do you need to mutate the original?

Comment: If mutate means change, then yes, the original list can be mutated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use

```
var stringsThatMeetCondition = strings.Where(condition);
var stringsThatDontMeetCondition = strings.Where(x => !condition(x));
```

Of course, you end up applying the condition to each element in the list twice. To avoid this you might want to write a generic splitting function, which wouldn't be as neat.

Comment: +1 This is the best way to do it in my opinion, unless performance indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<string, bool> condition = ...;
var groupedStrings = strings.GroupBy(condition)
var stringsMeetingCondition = groupedStrings.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key);
var stringsNotMeetingCondition = groupedStrings.FirstOrDefault(g => !g.Key);
```